# Open layer check if feature is in viewport

Tags: javascript, openlayers

My purpose is to display only features that have coordinate inside my map viewport (map area currently displayed).

I get the extent of the viewport by doing:

```
var mapExtent = this.map.getView().calculateExtent(this.map.getSize());
mapExtent = ol.proj.transformExtent(mapExtent, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
```

and after, in a loop where I am reading the element of one store,

```
var point = ol.proj.fromLonLat([
      element.get('longitude'),
      element.get('latitude')
]);

elementPoint = new ol.geom.Point(point);
var feature = new ol.Feature(elementPoint);
var coordsFeatures = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
```

and after, just to quickly see if the point is inside my viewport, I use just a console log:

```
console.log(ol.extent.containsXY(mapExtent, coordsFeatures[0],coordsFeatures[1]));
/*if(!ol.extent.containsXY(mapExtent, coordsFeatures[0],coordsFeatures[1])){
     return true;
}*/
```

But I don't know why, the result is only false, even if for sure there are points inside the map area currently displayed.

Whart I am doing wrong?

Comment: For such problem, you can print the coordinates and compare with what you are expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing projections.

For the extent, you change from 3857 to 4326.

For the point, by applying `ol.proj.fromLonLat()`, you change from 4326 to 3857 (the [default](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html))

Just use 3857 or 4326 for both

Answer (score 1):

So I will post the correct code in case someone else may need it. As mentioned by @GH (thank you again) my problem was the mixing projections, so I changed my code in this way:

instead of using the coordinate, I get the extent of the feature:

```
var extentFeature = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
```

and after i applied to it the same transformExtent used for the map:

```
extentFeature = ol.proj.transformExtent(extentFeature, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');

if(!ol.extent.containsExtent(mapExtent, extentFeature)){
   return true;
}
```

and now it works! :D